# мониторинг запросов к web-серверу Apache

Tags: apache

Есть VDS Ubuntu 16.04 + MySQL+ Apache+PHP и множество сайтов на нем.
Необходимо узнать сколько примерно запросов к серверу поступает каждую секунду. 
Желательно в реальном времени.

Что-то типа  70 r/s (request/second).

Если еще и график будет отображаться и еще какая-нибудь доп информация - будет здорово.

Comment: Я для этих целей использую zabbix. Количество запросов в секунду + график + доп.информация.

Answer (score 1):

1. настроить логгирование в Apache
2. натравить на логи вот это https://goaccess.io